# File Creation/Deletion Efficiency?

Tags: c++, performance, file

I'm writing code that occasionally needs to write data to a file, then send that file to another program for analysis, and repeat the process.

The format of the file is very rigid; headers are required, but they are unchanging and only about 10 lines. So I have two options:

**1.** Write a function to delete lines from the end of a file until I reach the header section.

**2.** Remove the old file and create a new file with the same name in its place, rewriting the header part every time.

So my question is this: are there significant efficiency issues in file creation and deletion? It seems easier to write that than to have to write a dynamic `deleteLines()` function, but I'm curious about the overhead involved. If it matters, I'm working in C++.

Comment: Can't you just use a pipe for this?

Comment: Why do you need to delete the other lines? Why cant you just copy over the header? Or better yet, read in the header and pass that over to your other program.

Comment: You might also want to just use a profiler to figure out which one is better.

Comment: In this particular case, delete/recreate or overwrite or modify are probably all going to be pretty much the same, since the files are so small (depending on their lifetime, they may not even make it out to disk). So it's probably not worth worrying about - just pick the easiest route. Now if the files were 10GB each, you might have a completely different choice to make...

Comment: @Dgrin91, you said it perfectly, altough I think this needs more emphasis. So to the OP: profile, profile, profile!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is, what actions do the different methods entail? Here are some answers:

Truncating a file means

1. Updating the inode controlling the file
2. Updating the filesystems information on free blocks

Deleting a file means

1. Updating the the directory that contains the link to the file
2. Decrementing the files reference count and updating the filesystems information on free blocks as necessary

Creating a file means

1. Creating an inode for it
2. Updating the the directory that is to contain the file
3. Updating the filesystems information on free blocks

Adding data to an empty file means

1. Allocating a block for the data, updating the filesystems information on free blocks
2. Updating the inode controlling the file

I think, it is clear that deleting/creating/appending a file entails quite a few more operations than simply truncating the file after the header.

However, as others have noted, if you want speed, use pipes or shared memory regions (for details look at the documentation of mmap()) or similar stuff. Disk are among the slowest thing ever built into a computer...

Ps: Ignoring performance while designing/choosing the algorithms is the evil root of all slow code... in this respect you better listen to Torvalds than to Knuth.

Comment: Under "Deleting a file", you also need "3. decrementing the reference count in the inode and freeing it if necessary"

Comment: Edited to reflect this (I had thought of that as being an implicit detail, but it's clearer this way).

Answer (score 1):

Performance in this case depends on many things, on the underlying file system etc. So, benchmark it. It will be quite easy to write and will give you the best answer.

And keep in mind Donand Knuth's statement:

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time:
>   premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the old file and writing a new one is probably faster since you would only keep a few bytes. If you modify the existing file, it has to first read the data, then write the new data. If you just go ahead and write there's just the write operation.

But the main point is that just writing the new file is probably far easier to implement and understand, so it should be your default choice unless and until you find that the application is not fast enough and profiling shows this particular piece to be a bottleneck.